# pick up value from slide bar once

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I want pick up value from slide bar when mouse move finished and don't want to label content change many times, my code:

```
    private void SecondsSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        this.SecondsLabel.Content = (int)this.SecondsSlider.Value;
    }
```

how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `DragCompleted` event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb.dragcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). 

It is fired after the user has released the MouseButton.

```
private void SecondsSlider_DragCompleted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.SecondsLabel.Content = (int)this.SecondsSlider.Value;
}
```

Usage in XAML:

```
<Slider Thumb.DragCompleted="SecondsSlider_DragCompleted" />
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you want to get the value only once from the slider.
You can use a static bool which once crested will not be created again, like this:

private void SecondsSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        static bool isPicked=false;
        If(!isPicked){
        this.SecondsLabel.Content = (int)this.SecondsSlider.Value;
        isPicked=true;
        }
    }

This way you'll only get the value once and change the bool isPicked's tp true, once it is changed to true you won't pick the value of the slider any more times.
I hope that solves your problem.

P.S: sorry if my answer wasn't properly formatted, the reason is that I'm using a phone right now.